# Form or jQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

When a form sends variable with GET Method, the URL changes, putting the variables that you are passing in this way

```
url?variable=....
```

How can I get the same result with jQuery Ajax? Is it possible? Thank you

Comment: Use the [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState().C2.A0method) method (or, change `location.hash`).

Comment: do you have problem sending it or retrieving it

Comment: You're the 1000th person asking it, answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/824349/601179

Answer (score 0):

set path in your php layout/view file where you include this code

```
<script>
   var path="<?php echo $this->webroot;?>";
</script>
```

and add following jquery *code* to post the data through ajax.

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: path+'homes/createEvent',
             data: {eventname:eventname,manager:manager},
         async: false,
         success: function(resulthtml)
                 {
        alert(resulthtml);
         },
         error: function(message)
                 {
        alert('error');
         }  
});
```

and on homes_controller.php, u will get this ajax data in createEvent function,

```
<?php
    function createEvent()
    {
       $eventName=$_POST['eventname'];
       $manager=$_POST['manager'];
    }
?>
```